# Let build.sbt define dependency on another local library

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

There lines up two modules in the same directory, and I want the one to depend on another. I know how to do it in Scala files in the project directory, however, I want the build.sbt to perform the same job with itself. Here is a not-working code that would hopefully communicate to you what I mean:

```
name := "foo"

libraryDependencies += ProjectRef(file("../bar"), "bar")
```

The error says:

> No implicit for Append.Value[Seq[sbt.ModuleID], sbt.ProjectRef] found, so sbt.ProjectRef cannot be appended to Seq[sbt.ModuleID].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to prefer a build definition in `project/Build.scala`, instead of `build.sbt`. But the following code within the object Build should also do for a standard `build.sbt`.

```
//Build.scala
import sbt._

object Build extends Build {
  lazy val projectA = project.in(file("a"))
  lazy val projectB = project.in(file("b")).dependsOn(projectA)
}
```

or:

```
//your root build.scala
name := "test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

val projectA = project.in(file("a"))
val projectB = project.in(file("b")).dependsOn(projectA)
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I am totally sure how to do it with Scala files in the `project` directory. My question is if we can do it without those files but only the `build.sbt` file. Thank you for answering, tho

Comment: As said, it will work for build.sbt as well. Assuming you have a project structure with two subprojects projectA and projectB. Just but the content of the above object into your root build.sbt

Comment: Oh, thank you for editing :) Now I got what you meant!